# Communication Between Two Virtual Machines

Tags: networking, windows-7, virtual-machine, virtualbox

My host operating system is Ubuntu 12.04, in which I have VirtualBox installed. Then I have two Windows 7 guest machines configured in the VirtualBox. I need to communicate between the two Windows machines. I have tried using Bridged Networking and Internal Networking with reference to the following article:

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

I used the same network name for both networking types in my experiments. However, I'm still unable to ping from one Windows machine to the other. If there is anyone who has done this, please give me some guideline how to do so.

Thank you.

Comment: Internal networking should do it. Maybe the Windows firewalls are blocking communication?

Answer (score 3):

It should work with Bridge networking, when both virtual boxes (and eventually also the host) will be on the same LAN.

HOWEVER, Notice that typically Windows will respond to ping request ONLY if there is at least one shared folder! If you don't have any shared folders, Windows will not return the ping, and that's where the problem may be.

So I suggest you share a folder on both Windows machines, set them up with bridge networking and try to ping again.

Hope that help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try the suggestions [here](http://dev.nirmalya.net/articles/setup/enabling-vm-to-be-accessed-from-virtualbox-host-and-other-computers-on-the-network). 
Working solution involves a combination of Bridged Adapter + NAT + Host-only Adapter.